# Return max of the value in view SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, max

I created this view as you can see here :

[image]

The result of my view is this :

[image]

but in fact I need two values: the max record of `fitupdetailid` and `weldetaildid.

I am new to SQL query. Can I add some filter to my view?

```
SELECT        
    dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdetailId, dbo.jointId.JointId, 
    dbo.weldDetail.WeldDetailId
FROM
    dbo.weldDetail 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.jointId ON dbo.weldDetail.jointid = dbo.jointId.JointId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.fitupdetail ON dbo.jointId.JointId = dbo.fitupdetail.jointid
```

I mean

```
101-2-51
201-1-1002
```

Comment: Please don't post images. Post in the form of text data. Please tell us your expected output.

Comment: I added to the post

Comment: The record with maximum of welddetaildId and fitupdetailid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

Using view:

```
select jointid,max(fitupdetailid),max(weldetaildid) from <yourviewname>
group by jointid
```

Using SQL:

```
SELECT        
    MAX(dbo.fitupdetail.fitupdetailId), dbo.jointId.JointId, 
    MAX(dbo.weldDetail.WeldDetailId
FROM
    dbo.weldDetail 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.jointId ON dbo.weldDetail.jointid = dbo.jointId.JointId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.fitupdetail ON dbo.jointId.JointId = dbo.fitupdetail.jointid
GROUP BY dbo.jointId.JointId
```

Comment: I test your solution for my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150261/groupby-in-view-of-sql-returns-aggregate-error but it doesn't work