# groupby in view of sql returns aggregate error

Tags: sql-server, view, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to create a view with this query as you can see here:

```
SELECT        dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, dbo.Joints.JointNumber, dbo.Joints.JointSize, dbo.Joints.ShopField, dbo.Joints.WPS, dbo.WeldDetails.StateStep2 AS WeldState, dbo.Welds.WeldNumber, 
                         dbo.FitUps.FitUpNumber, MAX(dbo.WeldDetails.Id) AS WeldDetailId, MAX(dbo.FitUpDetails.Id) AS FitupDetailId, dbo.Joints.Id AS JointId, dbo.Ends.Name, dbo.Joints.THK, dbo.FitUpDetails.StateStep2 AS FitupState,
                          dbo.Joints.Revision, dbo.Joints.Note
FROM            dbo.FitUps INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Welds INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Joints INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WeldDetails ON dbo.Joints.Id = dbo.WeldDetails.JointId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FitUpDetails ON dbo.Joints.Id = dbo.FitUpDetails.JointId ON dbo.Welds.Id = dbo.WeldDetails.WeldId ON dbo.FitUps.Id = dbo.FitUpDetails.FitUpId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Lines ON dbo.Joints.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Ends ON dbo.Joints.EndId = dbo.Ends.Id
GROUP BY dbo.Joints.Id
```

But when i want to save the view i get this error :
[image]

Here is a part of my data :
[image]

Every joint id can have multi `fitupdetailid` and `welddetailid` in my view i want just show the maximum value of `fitupdetailid` and `welddetailid` of my joint.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik yes let me post it to the question

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want ... but if just want to get rid of error then try following group by: 
GROUP BY dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, dbo.Joints.JointNumber, dbo.Joints.JointSize, dbo.Joints.ShopField, dbo.Joints.WPS, dbo.WeldDetails.StateStep2 , dbo.Welds.WeldNumber, 
         dbo.FitUps.FitUpNumber, dbo.Joints.Id , dbo.Ends.Name, dbo.Joints.THK, dbo.FitUpDetails.StateStep2 ,dbo.Joints.Revision, dbo.Joints.Note

Comment: @Mureinik you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147176/return-max-of-the-value-in-view-sql-server

Comment: @SagarShelke it doesn't work

Comment: @Mureinik did you see my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your query with a more readable join structure than what your GUI spit out. This should run for you and fix your error. Whether the results are what you want or not depends on your data. You may also want to re-order the grouping to group how you want, hierarchically. But all of those columns will need to be in the grouping in one form or another.

```
SELECT
    dbo.Lines.LineNumber, 
    dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, 
    dbo.Joints.JointNumber, 
    dbo.Joints.JointSize, 
    dbo.Joints.ShopField, 
    dbo.Joints.WPS, 
    dbo.WeldDetails.StateStep2 AS WeldState, 
    dbo.Welds.WeldNumber, 
    dbo.FitUps.FitUpNumber, 
    MAX(dbo.WeldDetails.Id) AS WeldDetailId, 
    MAX(dbo.FitUpDetails.Id) AS FitupDetailId, 
    dbo.Joints.Id AS JointId, 
    dbo.Ends.Name, 
    dbo.Joints.THK, 
    dbo.FitUpDetails.StateStep2 AS FitupState,
    dbo.Joints.Revision, 
    dbo.Joints.Note
FROM
    dbo.FitUps 
    INNER JOIN dbo.FitUpDetails ON dbo.FitUps.Id = dbo.FitUpDetails.FitUpId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Joints ON dbo.Joints.Id = dbo.FitUpDetails.JointId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.WeldDetails ON dbo.Joints.Id = dbo.WeldDetails.JointId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Welds ON dbo.Welds.Id = dbo.WeldDetails.WeldId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Lines ON dbo.Joints.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Ends ON dbo.Joints.EndId = dbo.Ends.Id
GROUP BY
    dbo.Lines.LineNumber, 
    dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, 
    dbo.Joints.JointNumber, 
    dbo.Joints.JointSize, 
    dbo.Joints.ShopField, 
    dbo.Joints.WPS, 
    dbo.WeldDetails.StateStep2,
    dbo.Welds.WeldNumber, 
    dbo.FitUps.FitUpNumber, 
    dbo.Joints.Id,
    dbo.Ends.Name, 
    dbo.Joints.THK, 
    dbo.FitUpDetails.StateStep2,
    dbo.Joints.Revision, 
    dbo.Joints.Note
```

Comment: Did you put a period somewhere? Double click the error... what line does it highlight?

Comment: on this line  :    INNER JOIN dbo.WeldDetails dbo.Joints.Id = dbo.WeldDetails.JointId

Comment: My bad... that was my fault @EhsanAkbar. i fixed it above